# Using queues results in asyncio exception "got Future <Future pending> attached to a different loop"

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I'm trying to run this simple code with asyncio queues, but catch exceptions, and even nested exceptions.

I would like to get some help with making queues in asyncio work correctly:

```
import asyncio, logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.getLogger("asyncio").setLevel(logging.WARNING)


num_workers = 1
in_queue = asyncio.Queue()
out_queue = asyncio.Queue()
tasks = []


async def run():
    for request in range(1):
        await in_queue.put(request)

    # each task consumes from 'input_queue' and produces to 'output_queue':
    for i in range(num_workers):
        tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(worker(name=f'worker-{i}')))
    # tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(saver()))

    print('waiting for queues...')
    await in_queue.join()
    # await out_queue.join()
    print('all queues done')

    for task in tasks:
        task.cancel()
    print('waiting until all tasks cancelled')
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=True)
    print('done')


async def worker(name):
    while True:
        try:
            print(f"{name} started")
            num = await in_queue.get()
            print(f'{name} got {num}')
            await asyncio.sleep(0)
            # await out_queue.put(num)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"{name} exception {e}")
        finally:
            print(f"{name} ended")
            in_queue.task_done()


async def saver():
    while True:
        try:
            print("saver started")
            num = await out_queue.get()
            print(f'saver got {num}')
            await asyncio.sleep(0)
            print("saver ended")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"saver exception {e}")
        finally:
            out_queue.task_done()


asyncio.run(run(), debug=True)
print('Done!')
```

Output:

```
waiting for queues...
worker-0 started
worker-0 got 0
worker-0 ended
worker-0 started
worker-0 exception 
worker-0 ended
ERROR:asyncio:unhandled exception during asyncio.run() shutdown
task: <Task finished coro=<worker() done, defined at temp4.py:34> exception=ValueError('task_done() called too many times') created at Python37\lib\asyncio\tasks.py:325>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Python37\lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 43, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "Python37\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 573, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "temp4.py", line 23, in run
    await in_queue.join()
  File "Python37\lib\asyncio\queues.py", line 216, in join
    await self._finished.wait()
  File "Python37\lib\asyncio\locks.py", line 293, in wait
    await fut
RuntimeError: Task <Task pending coro=<run() running at temp4.py:23> cb=[_run_until_complete_cb() at Python37\lib\asyncio\base_events.py:158] created at Python37\lib\asyncio\base_events.py:552> got Future <Future pending> attached to a different loop

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "temp4.py", line 46, in worker
    in_queue.task_done()
  File "Python37\lib\asyncio\queues.py", line 202, in task_done
    raise ValueError('task_done() called too many times')
ValueError: task_done() called too many times
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.1.4\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1664, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.1.4\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1658, in main
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.1.4\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1068, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.1.4\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "temp4.py", line 63, in <module>
    asyncio.run(run(), debug=True)
  File "Python37\lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 43, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "Python37\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 573, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "temp4.py", line 23, in run
    await in_queue.join()
  File "Python37\lib\asyncio\queues.py", line 216, in join
    await self._finished.wait()
  File "Python37\lib\asyncio\locks.py", line 293, in wait
    await fut
RuntimeError: Task <Task pending coro=<run() running at temp4.py:23> cb=[_run_until_complete_cb() at Python37\lib\asyncio\base_events.py:158] created at Python37\lib\asyncio\base_events.py:552> got Future <Future pending> attached to a different loop
```

This is the basic flow, what I would like to do later is run more requests on more workers where each worker will move the number from `in_queue` to `out_queue` and then the saver will print the numbers from `out_queue`.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Your queues must be created *inside the loop*. You created them outside the loop created for `asyncio.run()`, so they use `events.get_event_loop()`. `asyncio.run()` creates a new loop, and futures created for the queue in one loop can't then be used in the other.

Create your queues in your top-level `run()` coroutine, and either pass them to the coroutines that need them, or use [`contextvars.ContextVar` objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextvars.html#module-contextvars) if you must use globals.

You also need to clean up how you handle task cancelling inside your tasks. A task is cancelled by raising a [`asyncio.CancelledError` exception](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-exceptions.html#asyncio.CancelledError) *in the task*. You can ignore it, but if you catch it to do clean-up work, **you must re-raise it.**

Your task code catches all exceptions without re-raising, including `CancelledError`, so you block proper cancellations.

Instead, what *does* happen during cancellation is that you call [`queue.task_done()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-queue.html#asyncio.Queue.task_done); don't do that, at least not when your task is being cancelled. You should only call `task_done()` when you actually are handling a queue task, but your code calls `task_done()` when an exception occurs *while waiting for a queue task to appear*.

If you need to use `try...finally: in_queue.task_done()`, put this around the block of code that handles an item received from the queue, and keep the `await in_queue.get()` **outside** of that `try` block. You don't want to mark tasks done you didn't actually receive.

Finally, when you print exceptions, you want to print their `repr()`; for historical reasons, the `str()` conversion of exceptions produces their `.args` value, which is not very helpful for `CancelledError` exceptions, which have an empty `.args`. Use `{e!r}` in formatted strings, so you can see what exception you are catching:

```
worker-0 exception CancelledError()
```

So, corrected code, with the `saver()` task enabled, the queues created inside of `run()`, and task exception handling cleaned up, would be:

```
import asyncio, logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.getLogger("asyncio").setLevel(logging.WARNING)


num_workers = 1


async def run():
    in_queue = asyncio.Queue()
    out_queue = asyncio.Queue()

    for request in range(1):
        await in_queue.put(request)

    # each task consumes from 'in_queue' and produces to 'out_queue':
    tasks = []
    for i in range(num_workers):
        tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(
            worker(in_queue, out_queue, name=f'worker-{i}')))
    tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(saver(out_queue)))

    await in_queue.join()
    await out_queue.join()

    for task in tasks:
        task.cancel()

    await asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=True)

    print('done')

async def worker(in_queue, out_queue, name):
    print(f"{name} started")
    try:
        while True:
            num = await in_queue.get()
            try:
                print(f'{name} got {num}')
                await asyncio.sleep(0)
                await out_queue.put(num)
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"{name} exception {e!r}")
                raise
            finally:
                in_queue.task_done()
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        print(f"{name} is being cancelled")
        raise
    finally:
        print(f"{name} ended")

async def saver(out_queue):
    print("saver started")
    try:
        while True:
            num = await out_queue.get()
            try:
                print(f'saver got {num}')
                await asyncio.sleep(0)
                print("saver ended")
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"saver exception {e!r}")
                raise
            finally:
                out_queue.task_done()
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        print(f"saver is being cancelled")
        raise
    finally:
        print(f"saver ended")

asyncio.run(run(), debug=True)
print('Done!')
```

This prints

```
worker-0 started
worker-0 got 0
saver started
saver got 0
saver ended
done
worker-0 is being cancelled
worker-0 ended
saver is being cancelled
saver ended
Done!
```

If you want to use globals, to share queue objects, then use `ContextVar` objects. You still create the queues in `run()`, but if you were to start multiple loops then the `contextvars` module integration will take care of keeping the queues separate:

```
from contextvars import ContextVar
# ...

in_queue = ContextVar('in_queue')
out_queue = ContextVar('out_queue')

async def run():
    in_, out = asyncio.Queue(), asyncio.Queue()
    in_queue.set(in_)
    out_queue.set(out)

    for request in range(1):
        await in_.put(request)

    # ...

    for i in range(num_workers):
        tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(worker(name=f'worker-{i}')))
    tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(saver()))

    await in_.join()
    await out.join()

    # ...

async def worker(name):
    print(f"{name} started")
    in_ = in_queue.get()
    out = out_queue.get()
    try:
        while True:
            num = await in_.get()
            try:
                # ...
                await out.put(num)
                # ...
            finally:
                in_.task_done()
    # ...

async def saver():
    print("saver started")
    out = out_queue.get()
    try:
        while True:
            num = await out.get()
            try:
                # ...
            finally:
                out.task_done()
    # ...
```

Comment: I stumbled upon this helpful answer when I received the same error as @Shirkan, but when using an **asyncio.Lock**. These also must be created inside the same loop, (not in `__init__` or any other non-async or different-loop place).

Comment: @t-mart I am facing the same issue with asyncio.Lock how to fix that?

Comment: @NVS: read my answer. Any asyncio object that needs access to the active loop can only be created when there is a loop active, so in a function that is called from the call stack started with `asyncio.run()`

Answer (score 3):

When passing the queue as argument is not an option you could also explicitly initialize it with an event loop created in advance

```py
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
queue = asyncio.Queue(loop=loop)
```

In that case, however, you would be giving up the utility of `asyncio.run` method and would have to handle the start and shutdown of the event loop yourself

```py
try:
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    loop.set_debug(True)
    loop.run_until_complete(run())
finally:
    try:
        asyncio.runners._cancel_all_tasks(loop)
        loop.run_until_complete(loop.shutdown_asyncgens())
    finally:
        asyncio.set_event_loop(None)
        loop.close()
```

Comment: Deprecated since version 3.8, will be removed in version 3.10: The loop parameter.