# How to integrate Faust with Django?

Tags: python, django, django-3.0, faust, django-3.1

I am trying to integrate Faust with Django to publish the messages to Kafka.
Here is the example in Faust repo: https://github.com/robinhood/faust/tree/master/examples/django

I modified it a bit, and created views to push data to Kafka via Faust.

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync

from accounts.agents import AccountRecord, add_account


async def send_data() -> None:
    print("sending..data")
    print(await add_account.ask(AccountRecord(name="tesst", score=10.9, active=False)))

def index(request):
    async_to_sync(send_data)()
    return render(request, "accounts/index.html")
```

But, I get this error now:

> RuntimeError at / Task <Task pending name='Task-1'
> coro=<AsyncToSync.main_wrap() running at
> /Users/mysuer/.pyenv/versions/3.8.3/envs/faustdjango/lib/python3.8/site-packages/asgiref/sync.py:204>
> cb=[_run_until_complete_cb() at
> /Users/mysuer/.pyenv/versions/3.8.3/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py:184]>
> got Future  attached to a different loop

I am running this Django app using development server.
What am I doing wrong?
Anyone? :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53724665/using-queues-results-in-asyncio-exception-got-future-future-pending-attached

Comment: would you provide full code. And also, above link has same bug and answer. Did you check it?

Comment: @Maverick, how are you executing this in Django as the main app? As per the example of [faustapp](https://github.com/robinhood/faust/blob/master/examples/django/faustapp/app.py) they ensure to use the event loop by making sure the app which starts off uses the`faust.App()`

Comment: I believe that it happens when you try to run a function that execute itself in different thread (or process). As i can see in faustapp source code it is defined as async function so you can not call it as sync one.

Answer (score 3):

See the FAQ section in faust [documentation](https://github.com/robinhood/faust#can-i-use-faust-with-djangoflasketc)

**Can I use Faust with Django/Flask/etc.?**

Yes! Use `eventlet` as a bridge to integrate with `asyncio`.

Using **`eventlet`**

This approach works with any blocking Python library that can work with `eventlet`.

Using `eventlet` requires you to install the `aioeventlet` module, and you can install this as a bundle along with Faust:

```
$ pip install -U faust[eventlet]
```

Then to actually use eventlet as the event loop you have to either use the `-L <faust --loop>` argument to the `faust` program:

```
$ faust -L eventlet -A myproj worker -l info
```

or add `import mode.loop.eventlet` at the top of your entry point script:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import mode.loop.eventlet  # noqa
```

> Warning
> It's very important this is at the very top of the module, and that it executes before you import libraries.

Comment: This doesn't help at all, as it still doesn't explain how to send calls to agents from a view.  None of the documentation does - not even their Django example.

Comment: I am curious, with more async support to django views and orm's should we revisit faust integration examples with django?