# Get latest message from websockets queue in Python

Tags: python, websocket, python-asyncio

How do you get the last message received from server even if there are unread messages in queue?

Also, how could I ignore (delete) the rest of the unread messages?

CODE example:

```
while True:
    msg = await ws_server.recv()
    await do_something_with_latest_message(msg)
```

I Nead something like:

```
while True:
    msg = await ws_server.recv_last_msg() # On next loop I should "await" until a newer msg comes, not te receive the previous msg in LIFO order
    await do_something_with_latest_message(msg)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to do this natively, just with the `websockets` library. However, you could use an `asyncio.LifoQueue`:

```py
queue = asyncio.LifoQueue()

async def producer(ws_server):
    async for msg in ws_server:
        await queue.put(msg)

async def consumer():
    while True:
        msg = await queue.get()
        # clear queue
        while not queue.empty():
            await queue.get()
        await do_something_with_latest_message(msg)
await asyncio.gather(producer(ws_server), consumer())
```

Comment: I can't test it right now, but it seems like a solution

Comment: Second time the code goes through `async for msg in ws_server:` in `producer` function it raises this error `RuntimeError: Task <Task pending name='Task-11' coro=<consumer() running at xxx\main.py:139> cb=[_gather.<locals>._done_callback() at xxx\asyncio\tasks.py:767]> got Future <Future pending> attached to a different loop`. Line 139 referenced in the error is the `msg = await queue.get()` of the `consumer` function.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53724990/19846219) should solve your issue.

Comment: Nevermind, it's working. I call the `await asyncio.gather(prod, cons)` instruction inside an `async with websockets.connect` context manager, but the `asyncio.LifoQueue()` outside of it. I put the queue declaration inside the context manager and passed it as parameter to the `producer` and `consumer` and it's working now.